# IE8 height:100%; issue with scrollbar

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

After putting in `height:100%;` in html, body, and the first div with a image bg, I can no longer scroll down the page in IE 8. The scroll bar is visible but is non responsive. Cannot scroll with mouse scroll or page down key either. I had to put `height:100%;` so that the image in the div will fill the entire page even past the footer. Couldn't use the body bg because of the IE 8 gradient code. Any clue on what the issue is? The scroll does work in IE 9 however....

```
html, body {
height:100%;
color:#423928;
font:normal 13px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flash-bg { 
background:url(../images/ahrabg.png) repeat; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: how can you say *"the scrollbar doesn't work?"* does it move or not? do you have content that is long? what's your HTML? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: found the answer... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911167/why-doesnt-my-webpage-scroll-in-internet-explorer-8)

Answer (score -1):

Using "html" on the first line of css will not do anything - the html tag is to start the markup, not to be styled. Also, the body holds all the content, and so is automatically 100% of the page.

Comment: Both points you made are incorrect. Both the <html> and <body> elements extend as far as the content on the page does. Also, you can style the html element. For example, html {height: 100%;} is valid and has an effect on the page.