# What is "overflow:scroll\9" or "height:100%\9"?

Tags: html, css

I was looking through Twitter's CSS and I found this

```
.dm-threads {
height: 380px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll\9;
}
```

Then I've also found it as an answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360048/691525), but there's no information about this anywhere. So Can anyone clarify this for me ? What does the "\9" do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\9` is a hack For Internet Explorer 8 or below. That rule is only read for this explorers.

See more here **http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer**

Comment: note: IE9 picks up this style, too!